# Close child window from parent viewmodel wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, window

Close child `Window` after clicking ok/cancel.

I am invoking the child window from parent mvm model:

```
//parent view model
var optionSetViewModel = new OptionSetViewModel();
var optionSet = new OptionSet();
optionSet.SetViewModel(optionSetViewModel);

optionSet.SetOwner(_componentview);
optionSet.ShowDialog();
```

The code for ok and cancel for child `Window` is written in child view model:

```
private void OkClick()
{           
    _childWindow.Close();
}
```

It closing fine but after closing when it is returing to parent view model from where it is called it is throwing null reference exception. After close I am accesing the child window values:

```
_someText = optionSetViewModel.SomeText;
_noteText = optionSetViewModel.NoteText;
_optionsetLanguage = optionSetViewModel.OptionSetSelectedItem;
_optionsetselected = optionSetViewModel.OptionSetSelected.ToString();
```

Comment: we will need to see your code after `optionSet.ShowDialog();`

Comment: updated code ppls do check

Comment: You should let the Messenger Class handle the closing between ViewModels, it's way easier.

Comment: Have you overridden OnClosing() in your view, and does it dispose something or set a value to null?  If so, that's your null pointer.  When you debug your code, which pointer is null?  To debug this fastest, From the main menu click 'Debug' then 'Exceptions' and then checkmark the 2nd checkbox from the top on the left side.  Click OK and then run your app.  It will then stop on the line of code that is throwing the exception.  Hover over whatever variables are used to determine which one is null.

Comment: Hi Curtis thnx for suggestion i am only one one week old to wpf can send me an sample how to do that if you have some time pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Catel (see http://www.catelproject.com/) you can close a view based on a view model. Thus closing a view means a call like this:

```
myChildViewModel.CloseViewModel();
```

To show a child window:

```
var myChildViewModel = new MyChildViewModel();
uiVisualizerService.Show(myChildViewModel);
```